# Streamlining Python 3.6 -> 3.10 migration

Tags: python-3.x

We're finally migrating quite a bit of Python code from 3.6 to 3.10. Now, we could take the path of simply running everything under 3.10, seeing what breaks and fixing one by one.

But - I wonder if there's a better way. Is there any tool out there that can look at existing 3.6 code (and the requirements.txt of course) and identify what will break when moving to 3.10? Or maybe some other way of achieving this? An extensive online search didn't bring up anything, but it would make sense to me that there would be *some* solution.

I need to do the following:

1. For each package under requirements.txt, identify which don't support 3.10 in their current version, and find out the minimum version I need to move to that's supported in 3.10.
2. For the entire .py code base, identify which functions no longer exist in 3.10, and even highlight deprecated ones.

Comment: Someone has flagged this question for closing, saying it doesn't align with the community guidelines. However, I don't see where it contradicts https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Probably somebody voted to close your question because it's a request for a tool (offsite resource requests are off-topic), rather than a description of the problem you are trying to solve which you think you need a tool for. I suggest rephrasing your question to state the problem (i.e. you want to know in advance whether upgrading Python will break existing code) rather than your idea of what the solution would be (i.e. a tool).

Comment: To be clear, probably the solution to your problem does not involve any extra tool - just run with warnings enabled, check for `DeprecationWarning`s, if you see none then upgrade by two versions (i.e. 3.6 to 3.8) then repeat. Python only removes features after they are deprecated for at least two versions ([source](https://peps.python.org/pep-0387/)).

Comment: I updated the question @kaya3. The `DeprecationWarning` was something I was looking into, but the warnings are only triggered when a relevant function is called, rather than as compile-level warnings. I don't think we have full coverage of all of the Python code in tests, hence not sure all `DeprecationWarning`'s will be triggered in a test or simple run scenario.